# how to convert date like 09-Oct-2017 to 09-11-2017 by posixct?

Tags: r, date, posixct

I have a following datasets

[image]

I want to convert these rows in date datatype by using `Posixct`

right now I am using

```
as.POSIXct(q3_dos_log$INSERTED_ON   , format=c("%d-%mm-%Y"))
```

but giving wrong output, Kindly solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lubridate` library is your friend, which can parse many types of dates automatically (if it doesn't, you can specify what format the data is in, to help the package figure it out).

```
library(lubridate)
x = "28-Sep-2017"
as.POSIXct(parse_date_time(x, "dmy"))
```

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: Glad if it worked out. Feel free to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you found it useful. Also it's better if you post your data via `dput` rather than an image in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no need for `lubridate` here in my opinion; just use base R's `as.POSIXct`:

```
as.POSIXct("09-Oct-2017", format = "%d-%b-%Y")
#[1] "2017-10-09 AEDT"
```

Reformat as `"09-10-2017"` string:

```
format(as.POSIXct("09-Oct-2017", format = "%d-%b-%Y"), format = "%d-%m-%Y")
# [1] "09-10-2017"
```

Comment: Thnks it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

We could use `anydate` from `anytime` to pick up the formats automatically

```
anytime::anydate("09-Oct-2017")
#[1] "2017-10-09"
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is as.Date in Base R and knowledge of the formatting options for dates:

```
as.Date("07-May-2017", format = "%d-%B-%Y")
```

See more here: https://www.google.se/amp/s/www.r-bloggers.com/date-formats-in-r/amp/